# Using the word with

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct:

> (1) I will provide you with a car. OR
>   (2) I will provide a car to you.

Does Sentence 1 mean that the person and the car will be provided together?

Comment: This sentence [provides me an excuse](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22provides+me+an+excuse%22) to demonstrate that you don't always need the preposition ***with*** in such contexts. Both your sentences mean exactly the same - they just reverse the syntactic roles of primary and secondary objects. Same as *He gave her the answer / He gave the answer to her*, for example, which again are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. "**Provide**" as a transitive verb can act both ways and mean the same thing - '*to give someone something that they want or need*' ([**Macmillan Dictionary**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/provide)):

- **provide someone with something** - *The lecture provided him with an opportunity to meet one of his heroes.*
- **provide something for someone** - *The hotel provides a playroom for children.*
- **provide something to someone** - *We provide legal advice and services to our clients.*

The difference is only between placing either the *direct* or the *indirect* object first.

You may find this topic about the difference between prepositions with the word "**provide**" interesting - **[Prepositions with the verb "provide"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55925/preposition-with-verb-provide)**

Answer (score 0):

You are being confused by the nature of the objects. In both sentences, the meaning is the same. But look closely, the first sentence has a clear direct object. What is provided? A car. Who is it provided to? You. The car is the direct object and "you" is the indirect object. In the case of the first sentence, because you use **with**, the car becomes the object of preposition but is still the direct object.