# 'Provides me with an excuse" or "Provides me an excuse"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, direct-objects, indirect-objects

With respect to **FumbleFingers** for providing his Google search of "**provides me an excuse**" [in this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128458/using-the-word-with#comment258942_128458) I would like to ask when and in which cases can we omit "**with**" when we place the indirect object right before the direct object after the verb "**provide**"?

I searched in **Oxford**, **Cambridge**, **Macmillan**, **Collins**, **Longman**, and **Merriam-Webster** dictionaries and none of them allow us to use a direct object right after the indirect object with the verb "**provide**" without the preposition "**with**" in between. That is, **it is wrong to say** "**provide somebody something**".

Comment: I think you will find the absence of **with** as in "provides me an excuse" to correlate with a somewhat more formal register. It is certainly grammatical. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22provides%20us%20a%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I can understand that it is grammatical, but I can't find reference to this grammar and any explanation.

Comment: See page 40 here. https://books.google.com/books?id=d-TmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22ditransitive+verbs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-oufjkubWAhUDPiYKHSxXAJYQ6AEIRjAG#v=snippet&q=provide&f=false

Comment: Of relevance: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11583/provides-information-on-of-or-about-somthing?rq=1

Comment: **From Collins English Usage 2003**: You can say that you provide someone with what they want. _Mrs Castle had provided her with a list. The government cannot provide all young people with a job._
Note that you **must use with** in sentences like these. You **do not say** that you _provide someone what they want._

Comment: @Mv Log: I've cited hundreds of examples where "provide someone something" is the pattern, without **with**. Both patterns are grammatical, at least in AmE.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo "hundreds of examples" don't make a phrase grammatical. We need an authoritative source.

Comment: @Mv Log: You're wrong about that. An "authoritative source" would consult usage in the wild and report on current behavior. Grammatical is what people does. And I've cited such a source above (page 40, which cites Quirk).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo And one does read there: "which would be considered ungrammatical today" That's a casualism today. Maybe it will make it back into English, but for the time being it should be avoided by the careful writer.

Comment: @Mv Log: but read the footnote. It is perfectly grammatical in AmE and appears in many academic texts.  It isn't a sloppy usage.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's a very good link. However, as I can see, it's ungrammatical but common in AmE.

Comment: @SovereignSun: It is not ungrammatical in AmE. And historically in English it was not ungrammatical. https://books.google.com/books?id=agpFAQAAMAAJ&q=%22provide+them+a%22&dq=%22provide+them+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieiNOqtubWAhVJxoMKHescDigQ6AEILTAB

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=IbLTAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22provide+them+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidv4C-t-bWAhVK5YMKHW6ND30Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20them%20a%22&f=false or https://books.google.com/books?id=ky9VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA257&dq=%22provide+them+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidv4C-t-bWAhVK5YMKHW6ND30Q6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20them%20a%22&f=false or https://books.google.com/books?id=9XwPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&dq=%22provide+them+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ0PSQuObWAhVrzIMKHWDdDh0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20them%20a%22&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a British vs American English issue. **The Cambridge Guide to English Usage:** Convention dictates that certain verbs and related words are followed by particular prepositions/particles. Words like *compare/comparison* take either *with or to*, and *differ/different* may take *from, to or than*, depending on the context, and which part of the English-speaking world you belong to. In Britain you *ﬁll in* a form, whereas in the US you would express it as *ﬁll out*. Note also the fact that, in American English, no preposition at all is needed with some verbs which do require one in British English. Compare:

**British -- American**

cater for a party -- cater a party

protest against the war -- protest the war

provide us with a plan -- provide us a plan

wrote to his MP -- wrote his Congressman

Comment: Interestingly, in Canadian English (at least as I hear it spoken), any of these forms can be heard, although some are more common than others.

Comment: Since **provide {recipient} {something}** was used in England in the 19th century, I wouldn't say it was a BrE versus AmE thing at all, but a PDE (British) versus a 19th c. BrE thing.  The British began to consider it ungrammatical.